Spectral clustering with laplacian matrix eigenvector
I want to separate a given graph in $k$ clusters with the laplacian matrix ($L = D-A$ where $D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ the adjacency matrix).
How can the eigenvectors of $L$ be used, along with the $k$-means algorithm, to separate a graph ? How does it work ?
